# Frontend Web to run python scripts

Tags: python, web, scripting, frameworks, frontend

I am pretty firm in python scripting **(boto3)** now want to develop some sort of **frontend dash board** that would've buttons or list to execute script and give the output.

There are many options flask, bottle, django etc but I want to learn which will be ideal for my case and has modern framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you should go to javascript...
what framework you have said are all backend framework.
As I know,in the web development python is always in the backend.

so if you wanna develop frontend,go to learn html,css,javascript is only option.